# How to add maven nature to studio project programatically

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin

I want to add maven nature to my existing studio project through java code.
In eclipse , we can do so by **right click->configure->convert To Maven** option.
How can I invoke it through java code? 
My scenario is , I have added  **right click->menu->generate POM** option for project and on click of this I will be generating POM file for project and then I want to add maven nature to it in the same click. 
Can I invoke eclipses default code for converting to maven from my java code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured out the solution. We can add maven nature to project as given below - 
I have a eclipse project.

```
import org.eclipse.core.resources.ICommand;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IProjectDescription;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.NullProgressMonitor;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchWindow;

private void addMavenNature( IProject project){
   IProjectDescription desc = project.getDescription();

   String[] prevNatures = desc.getNatureIds(); //it takes all previous natures of project i.e studioNature,javanature
   String[] newNatures = new String[prevNatures.length + 1];

   System.arraycopy(prevNatures, 0, newNatures, 0, prevNatures.length);

   newNatures[prevNatures.length] = "org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature"; //add maven nature to the project
   desc.setNatureIds(newNatures);

   project.setDescription(desc, new NullProgressMonitor());

   ICommand[] commands = desc.getBuildSpec();
   List<ICommand> commandList = Arrays.asList( commands );
   ICommand build = new BuildCommand();
   build.setBuilderName("org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder"); //add maven builder to the project
   List<ICommand> modList = new ArrayList<>( commandList );
   modList.add( build );
   desc.setBuildSpec( modList.toArray(new ICommand[]{}));
}
```

Comment: please include the details of what is `project` here? where do you import `IProjectDescription`, `ICommand` from? and also a brief over how the project is converted into a maven project using the above code.